# Does tag like <div> and <span> inherit or not

Tags: html, css

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) it says:

> The HTML <div> element is the generic container for flow content and **does not inherently represent anything**.

It also says:

> The HTML <span> ... **does not inherently represent anything**.

However, my code shows `div` and `span` do inherit `color` attribute from `body` tag:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
     body{
         color: red;
         text-align: center;
     }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        test div
    </div>
    <span>test span</span>
</body>

</html>
```

In the above code, both `test div` and `test span` are red and centered. So how to interpret MDN's word?

Comment: There’s quite a big difference between “inheriting something” and “representing something inherently”.

Comment: Seems the problem is with the English language, not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a reading comprehension mistake, not a programming question as defined by the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [a dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inherently). Inherent (with an **en**) and inherit (with an **i**) are different words with different meanings.:

> inherently
>
> In a permanent, essential, or characteristic way.

The sentences are talking about the semantics expressed by the elements. They have absolutely nothing to do with CSS [inheritance](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inherit):

> inherit
>
> Derive (a quality, characteristic, or predisposition) genetically from one's parents or ancestors